# Can we use python with react?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, reactjs

I have seen many people are using **Nodejs** with **reactjs** but I liked **python** and **react** so much that I wanted to know if I could **python** with **react**. If so could you please give me some links for learning that please

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Seen as React has a client side DOM api, anything that can generate a website, can use React.

Comment: Well NodeJS and Python can both be used to create a back-end and since React is meant for the front-end I would guess they can be used together. A quick Google search yielded [this](https://realpython.com/the-ultimate-flask-front-end/) article for example.

Answer (score 25):

I have experience building web applications using React and Python Flask together, so perhaps I can help.

I do not know of a way to directly use Python on client-side web applications, but there are certainly plenty of ways to use Python on the backend. The most popular Python web frameworks are [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/#) and [Django](https://www.google.com/search?q=django&oq=django&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j0l3.2488j1j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

> If so could you please give me some links for learning that please

YouTuber Corey Schafer has [a great YouTube tutorial series on Flask](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MwZwr5Tvyxo), which I would wholeheartedly recommend.

Once you get more comfortable with web development in Python, I think the website https://realpython.com/ has great tutorials for both specific questions (e.g. [Token-Based Authentication in Flask](https://realpython.com/token-based-authentication-with-flask/)) and more general tutorials.

If you go with Django, it has a great ORM built in for working with databases.

If you go with Flask, which is definitely more beginner friendly IMO, I would  recommend [Peewee ORM](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/) for working with relational databases unless you have more complicated use-cases, in which case [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) is the de-facto standard.

Good luck learning!

---

**Update**

I just came across this cool Python library called [Transcrypt](https://github.com/QQuick/Transcrypt) that transpiles Python code into JavaScript, so it turns out you can write client-side code for the web in Python. Their website has some [cool tutorials](https://www.transcrypt.org/examples).

Answer (score 5):

Yes. React is mostly agnostic of what's going on at the server-level.
ie it does not care what backend you use.

Check this example : https://realpython.com/the-ultimate-flask-front-end/

Comment: Not entirely true if you want to do server-side rendering of React components.

Answer (score 5):

https://plotly.com/dash

I have been using this to build up react app with python.
They have new libs 'dash' and dash component whose underlying is react.js.

Answer (score 3):

React is backend-agnostic.

React manages the UI, which possibly interacts with some HTTP APIs regardless in what language they're made of.

What's important is that your API use some standard like [REST](https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/whatisrest.html), [jsonapi](https://jsonapi.org/) or [GraphQL](http://graphql.org) so you can benefit a wide range of tools (documentation, tests...)

That said, if you want to make "server-side-rendered" react web apps, like [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) does, or if you need WebSockets, you'll need NodeJS on the server-side too. Also, the ability to use the same code, tooling and ecosystem on the client and the server is useful for a developer.